# How to identify type of a media stream in Webrtc?

Tags: javascript, node.js, webrtc, video-streaming

I am finding a solution for identifying the type of mediastreams to know what is shared by the sender ( camera or screen share )
I tried to add label property in mediastream from sender side but it doesn’t work.
Can we add some additional details in session description protocol on sender side when sending streams using addTrack() ?

Comment: you can use track.kind to check track type

Comment: @RK_oo7 track.kind only returns “video” or “audio” but how will you differentiate between camera and screen sharing because both return “video” in track.kind for this case.

Comment: Are you able to find out track.label inside tracks?